# Intellij's keymap keeps resetting

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

My intellij keymap resets everytime I restart my system or sometimes when I install a new plugin. IF it matters, I'm working on win XP with very limited capacity - only 1 drive with 25 GB capacity. However, there's still 7 GB free space. Any idea why this is happening & how can this be avoided?

Comment: Check that [config folder](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) is not changed externally between restarts, see if there are any related errors in [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446).

Comment: I checked this, it's full of this exception.. INFO - ions.SchemesManagerFactoryImpl - Cannot save settings for com.intellij.openapi.options.SchemesManagerImpl com.intellij.openapi.vfs.InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: .../.IdeaIC11/config/keymaps

Comment: Try [changing the locations](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963) of IDEA folders.

Comment: Changing the location worked for me. Thanks @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 0):

In some cases default user profile directory used for settings storage may not have enough permissions or may be redirected to a network drive. In this case it's [recommended to change it](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348963).